# Jquery Slider required

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://www.avenuesocial.com/

plz check this site and please help me to find out this slider exactly this one. any
 help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please read through [ask].

Comment: This is not how we work here on [so].  If you have  **specific** question you need to provide more details on what exactly you are having difficulty with.  Don't expect us to go reverse engineer some one else's site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://kevinbatdorf.github.com/codaslider/